# Merging two Dataframes based on Time column

Tags: regex, r, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes based on `Time` column. They each have differently formatted values for time. They look the following way:

Example datasets for `Labourproductivity` and `Depressiondframe`:

```
Labourproductivity <- read.csv(text="
Time,LabourProductivity
2004 Q1,96.6
Q2,96.9
Q3,96.9
Q4,97.1
2005 Q1,97.6
Q2,99.0")
Depressiondframe <- read.csv(text="
Time,DepressionCount
2004.00,875
2004.25,820
2004.50,785
2004.75,857
2005.00,844")
```

Data:

```
Labourproductivity
     Time LabourProductivity
1 2004 Q1               96.6
2      Q2               96.9
3      Q3               96.9
4      Q4               97.1
5 2005 Q1               97.6
6      Q2               99.0
Depressiondframe
     Time DepressionCount
1 2004.00             875
2 2004.25             820
3 2004.50             785
4 2004.75             857
5 2005.00             844
```

How would I be able to merge the two dataframes based on `Time`?

Comment: @zx8754 how about adding the language tag too when editing :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg somehow missed it, also, this question is more about converting `2001 Q1` to `2000.00` than `merge`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible approach. We will use the `zoo` package which will easily convert `Depressiondframe$Time` to the desired format using `zoo::as.yearqtr` function, while the second one is trickier and we will use `stringi::stri_extract_first_regex` and `zoo::na.locf` in order to handle it. Then, just a simple `merge` will finish the task

```
library(zoo)
library(stringi)
Depressiondframe$Time <- as.character(as.yearqtr(Depressiondframe$Time))
Labourproductivity$Time <- with(Labourproductivity,
                                paste(na.locf(stri_extract_first_regex(Time, "\\d{4}")), 
                                stri_extract_first_regex(Time, "Q\\d")))

merge(Depressiondframe, Labourproductivity, by = "Time", all = TRUE)
#      Time DepressionCount LabourProductivity
# 1 2004 Q1             875               96.6
# 2 2004 Q2             820               96.9
# 3 2004 Q3             785               96.9
# 4 2004 Q4             857               97.1
# 5 2005 Q1             844               97.6
# 6 2005 Q2              NA               99.0
```